# What's the best place to store and load static data for plugins?

Tags: plugin-development

I have static data that my plugin requires as an array (multidimensional with 100s of items), it doesn't need to change and it seems overkill to store in a database and not appropriate as just arrays in my code.

Options I have considered:

- Json files - load them in
- In the config file

Which is best and is there a more appropriate way to store access?

Answer (score 4):

What format is the source data in?  If it's already in a multidimensional PHP array, then it might be as simple as having a `data.php` file in your plugin and doing a `require_once` in your plugin's `init()` method and you're good to go.

Even if it's in a different format, loading it from `init()` and parsing it into the multidimensional array is a good option.